# Status of Raghavendra's algorithm for solving linear systems in finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

In 2012, [Lipton wrote a blog entry](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/a-new-way-to-solve-linear-equations/) about a new algorithm for solving linear systems over finite fields by Prasad Raghavendra.

The [link to Raghavendra's draft paper on the topic is now dead](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~prasad/linsystems.pdf), and I can't find anything on the subject on Raghavendra's website.

Is the result correct? Is a write-up available anywhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The paper by Raghavendra is now also published and available [here](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2016/6206/pdf/LIPIcs-ICALP-2016-79.pdf) under the title:

*Correlation Decay and Tractability of CSPs*, appeared in the 43rd International Colloquium on Automata, Languages, and Programming (ICALP 2016).

A related article has appeared in the Electronic Colloquium on Computational Complexity, Report No. 7 (2015), available [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01598).

Comment: Can you give details that will enable us to find the paper in the future if this link stops working?  Maybe paper title, authors, and where published (if anywhere)?

Comment: The link is down, please could you tell us the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: The Links still should both work, please try again!

Answer (score 11):

This is a paper that seems to improve upon the result. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.3995.pdf